# Does caffeine increase the speed at which sperm travels?

Tags: biochemistry

I'm not even sure if this claim is true, but...

[This source](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080201004454AAKGOq5) states that

> Caffeine gives both types of sperm a boost, but the Y-sperm would get a little more of a boost.

[This article](http://www.babyhopes.com/articles/how-to-conceive-a-boy.html) reinforces the quote. In fact, this "tip" can be seen all over the internet to preferentially conceive a male rather than a female.

My question is how. **What is happening at the molecular to increase the overall mobility of sperm?** It clearly wouldn't work as a neurotransmitter (as it "normally" works).

Comment: I also realize that this question could be formatted for Skeptics.SE. Feel free to edit the question so that it's more suited for this site.

Comment: [This answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/780/69) suggests that the "extra boost" could be due to all Y sperm being lighter and therefore perhaps faster than X sperm - regardless of caffeine consumption.

Comment: @RoryM I'm familiar with that, as the comments to this answer also suggest: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1062/x-chromosome-weight

Comment: I'm more interested in the "boost" itself rather than the differential boost.

Comment: Ah it was that question I was trying to find earlier xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cell response for caffeine, is at the molecular level of RyR (Ryanodine receptor), and the main effect could be a temporal rise in Ca+2 cytosolic concentration, so it can change the electrical behavior for the whole cell, and then affect their mobility. But the main area for RyR research is at spermatogenesis, there are a lot of papers like [this one](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9770782), for that topic